# Can I safely output data to the user using this sanitize

Tags: php, javascript, xss, sanitization

So im trying to work out the best way to sanitize xss for safe output to the user.

More or less, when storing values from a form, im using strip_tags(); then bind_params();

And when Im about to output the data to the user Im also using htmlentities();

The data will only be shown inside `<p>` and `<a>` tags.

eg:

```
<p> Some data from user </p>

<a href=""> Some data from user </p>
```

Should this work?

Index.php

```
<form action="sante.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And then sante.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["fname"]; 
$age = $_POST["age"];

$namn = strip_tags($name); // then storing into mysql with bind_param
$older = strip_tags($age); // then storing into mysql with bind_param


 // before output, htmlentities

   function safe( $value ) {
  htmlentities( $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );

  return $value;
}


// Now showing values

echo safe($namn). "<br>";

echo "<p>" .safe($older) . "</p>";


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this code safely. I see you're already using `bind_param` (and I assume either the `mysqli` or `PDO` library), which prevents SQL injection (damage to you), and `htmlentities`, which prevents cross-site scripting (damage to the user).

You don't even need to call `strip_tags` before writing to the database, although it's a fine idea if you don't want user input to contain any JS/PHP/HTML tags at all (and also if you forget to call your `safe` function on output).

Comment: Thanks, yeah the user should only be allowed pure text

Answer (score 0):

When you insert data to database you must use mysql_real_escape_string or use PDO,
if you display data you must use htmlspecialchars

Comment: Thank you, I am using mysqli bind_param/prepare